# java.sql.SQLException: Could not  lock table 'change'; currently in use by user

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, ms-access-2003, sqlexception

Here is my problem, i wrote a program on jdbc concept everything was fine it compiles and runs without errors. where comes to problem as i need to alter the values of row by deleting
 the previous row(as the table contains only one row), and need to add column if required using the program , these both operations were successful only when any one is done.

But as these two operations were done on same frame. when i altered the rows, after a successful
 updation of row, i can't insert a new column. And when i trying to insert the column it is showing an error as

```
java.sql.SQlException:[Micros​oft][ODBC Micro Access Driver] Could not
 lock table 'change' ; currently in use by user 'admin' on 'machine
 chiru-pc
```

here 'change' is the table in which these alterations are done.

Can any one clear me how can i rectify this error?

---

---

---

here is the code i used

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    class Change extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
JButton done,ok,add;
JLabel[] c = new JLabel[50]; 
JLabel[] o = new JLabel[50]; 
JLabel lsx,lad,ln,lo,lc,la;
JTextField[] tf = new JTextField[50];
JTextField t;
int i=0,noc=0,d,h=0;
int[] e=new int[50];
String s;
Connection con; 

 public Change()
        {
        try{Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){System.out.println(ce);}
        try{con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TAILORING");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        Dimension screensize =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screensize.width,screensize.height);
            setTitle("STITCHING COST DETAILS"); 
                setLayout(null);  
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from change");
        ResultSetMetaData r=rs.getMetaData();
        noc=r.getColumnCount();
        done=new JButton("DONE");
        ok=new JButton("OK");
        add=new JButton("ADD");
        t=new JTextField(50);
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++){c[i] =new JLabel();}
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++){o[i] =new JLabel();}
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++){tf[i] =new JTextField(30);}
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++){c[i].setText(r.getColumnName(i));c[i].setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,20));}
        ResultSet ra=st.executeQuery("select * from change");
        while(ra.next())
            {
                if(d==0){for(i=1;i<=noc;i++){o[i].setText(String.valueOf(ra.getInt(i)));o[i].setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,20));}}
                d++;
            }
        lad= new JLabel("SRIHARIPURAM,VISAKHAPATNAM-11  ////  MASTER: CH. SRI RAMAKRISHNA");
        lad.setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,15));
        lsx=new JLabel("SUNNEX TAILORS");
        lsx.setFont(new Font("Algerian",Font.ITALIC,80));
        lc= new JLabel("COSTUME LIST");
        lc.setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,15));
        lo= new JLabel("OLD RATES");
        lo.setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,15));
        ln= new JLabel("NEW RATES");
        ln.setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,15));
        la= new JLabel("ADD NEW COSTUME");
        la.setFont(new Font("Narkisim",Font.ITALIC,15));
        add(lsx,(screensize.width/3)-(screensize.width/25),(screensize.height/25),710,100);
        add(lad,(screensize.width/3),(screensize.height/8),610,40);
        add(lc,(screensize.width/5),180,100,20);
        add(lo,(screensize.width/3),180,610,20);
        add(ln,(screensize.width/2),180,610,20);
        add(done,(screensize.width/2)+(screensize.width/6),(screensize.height/3),100,20);
        add(ok,(screensize.width/2),(screensize.height)-(screensize.height/7),100,20);
        add(add,(screensize.width/4),(screensize.height)-(screensize.height/7),100,20);
        add(t,(screensize.width/4),(screensize.height)-(screensize.height/5),100,20);
        add(la,(screensize.width/4),(screensize.height)-(screensize.height/4),200,20);
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++)
            {
                add(c[i],(screensize.width/5),(200+(30*i)),100,20);
            }
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++)
            {
                add(o[i],(screensize.width/3),(200+(30*i)),100,20);
            }
        for(i=1;i<=noc;i++)
            {
                add(tf[i],(screensize.width/2),(200+(30*i)),100,20);
            }
            add.addActionListener(this);
            ok.addActionListener(this);
            done.addActionListener(this);
        }catch(SQLException ce){System.out.println(ce);}
    }
public void add(JComponent c,int x,int y,int w,int h)
    {
        c.setBounds(x,y,w,h);
            add(c);
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(ae.getSource() ==ok)
            {   
                setVisible(false);  
                Tailoring t=new Tailoring();
            }
        if(ae.getSource() ==add)
            {
                setVisible(false);
                Add a=new Add();

            }
        if(ae.getSource() ==done)
            {   

                try{Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");}
                catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){System.out.println(ce);}
                try{con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:TAILORING");
                Statement st=con.createStatement();d=0;
            ResultSet ra=st.executeQuery("select * from change");
            while(ra.next())
            {
                if(d==0)
                {for(i=1;i<=noc;i++)
                    {
                    if(h==0){s=(Integer.parseInt(tf[i].getText())+",");}
                    else if(h==(noc-1)){s+=(Integer.parseInt(tf[i].getText()));}
                    else if(h!=0 && h!=noc){s+=(Integer.parseInt(tf[i].getText())+",");}
                    h++;
                    }d++;
                }
            }
            st.execute
            (
                "DELETE FROM change"
            );
                st.execute
                (
                    "insert into change values("+s+")"
                );

                }catch(SQLException ce){System.out.println(ce);}
                try {Thread.sleep(500);}
                catch(InterruptedException e){}
                setVisible(false);
                Change c=new Change();
            }
        }
}
```

here this class change is a sub class and not the main class

Comment: We need precisely concise code you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are logged into same database/table using admin role through GUI. Logoff from the GUI and run your program again.

Comment: it seems to be a problem when i need to insert more number of columns , if 5 columns are to be inserted i have to close the GUI for 5 times.

Comment: You cant do any modification to table while same table is opened from ms access database.

Comment: can i close and reopen database using some coding without closing gui

Comment: It seems someone was able to do it through VBA, but I don't think it is possible through Java. Here is link http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1633077-force-write-table-while-form-still-open.html

Answer (score 0):

You should **commit** your changes before attempt to run your DDL i.e. adding a new column to the table.

Comment: hi anubhav ya as u said it works but i need them to be done in either way- adding rows after inserting column or a column after inserting rows

Comment: You can do all writes to the database (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) in same transaction without any need to COMMIT in between however in order to add a new column into some table that table should not be locked which happens because of your earlier writes. So I would suggest you to first add column and then execute WRITE operations to your table.

Comment: k thank u anubhav, then there are no other options to unlock the table

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql command line, try executing:

```
show full processlist;
```

and look for the process that might be holding a lock on your table.

If you find one, and you want to kill it, note the `id` column. You can do one of two things:

- Kill the connection and anything its doing: `kill number_in_id_column`
- Kill the query (but leave the connection intact): `kill query number_in_id_column`

Comment: Bohemian i am using ms access as database in my program how can i know it in as access i mean the one holding the lock

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with the `mysql` tag when it seems it's an `ms access` question?! You must be careful with the tags! So, it is **not** a mysql question?

Answer (score 0):

i created a new class Add where i can add a required number of columns on one click, i succeeded by doing this, now its not showing the error what i posted.